# Keras LSTM input dimension

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm

def train_model_lstm(train_x, train_y, classes):
    train_x, train_y = np.array(train_x), np.array(train_y)
    train_x = np.reshape(train_x, (train_x.shape[0], train_x.shape[1], 1))

```
data_dim = 1
timesteps = train_x.shape[1]

regressor = Sequential()

regressor.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(timesteps, data_dim)))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(LSTM(units=50))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(Dense(len(classes), activation='softmax'))
regressor.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

regressor.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=2, batch_size=32)
```

I'm trying to feed my network and using LSTM algorithm to my chatbot
I got an error:

exception ! Error when checking : expected lstm_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (367, 1)

Someone can advise how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to provide the shapes of your final train_x and train_y next time.

I think that's where the error is.

Can you confirm that the shape of train_x is: **(length of the dataset, timesteps, data_dim)** and the train_y is **(length of dataset, len(classes))** ?

Comment: Do you have another suggestion ? for this LSTM algorithm

Comment: Use Embedding Words